# Fubini-Tonelli and Lebesgue Integral exercise

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, characteristic-functions

Let $A,B \subset \mathbb R$ measurable subsets and $h:\mathbb R \to\overline{\mathbb R}$ defined s $h(x)=m((A-x) \cap B)$. Show that $h$ is measurable and that it satisfies $\int_{\mathbb R}h(x)dx=m(A)m(B)$

This is what I could do:

If we consider $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x,y)=\chi_{A-x}(y)\chi_B(y)$, then we have  $f(x,y)=\chi_{(A-x) \cap B}(y)$. By Fubini-Tonelli, $$\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb R}(\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_{(A-x) \cap B}(y)dy)dx$$$$=\int_{\mathbb R} m((A-x)\cap B)dx$$$$=\int_{\mathbb R}h(x)dx$$

So $h(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} \chi_{(A-x) \cap B}(y)dy$, then $h$ is a measurable function.

I don't know what to do in order to prove that $$\int_{\mathbb R}h(x)dx=m(A)m(B)$$

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: reverse the order of integration and use translation invariance - a one line proof really

Comment: I guess $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, isn't it? Then, it is translation invariant.

Comment: Humm...  First of all you should prove that $f$  is measurable.  Then your conclusion that $h$ is measurable is OK.   Second, to compute $h$ you must reverse the order of integration: use the fact that $\chi_{(A-x)}(y)\chi_B(y) = \chi_{(A-y)}(x)\chi_B(y)$, integrate on $x$ and get $m(A-y)\chi_B(y)$, use the fact that Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, get $m(A)\chi_B(y)$, integrate on $y$.

Comment: It is important to prove $f$ is measurable.  In fact, $f$ is measurable, but do you know how to prove it?  **Hint**: $f(x,y)=\chi_{A}(x+y)\chi_B(y)$.

Comment: Hey Ramiro, I know this is an old question but I am not sure how to justify correctly the measurability of $f$. I know that if $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ is product of two measurable functions, then $h$ is measurable. In this case, $f(x,y)$ is not exactly the product of two measurable functions of one variable, so how can I show that $f$ is measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be 
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb R^2} f(x,y)&=\int_{\mathbb R}\left(\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_{(A-x) \cap B}(y)dy\right)dx
\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R}\left(\int_{B}\chi_{(A-x) }(y)dy\right)dx
\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R}\left(\int_{B}\chi_{A }(y+x)dy\right)dx
\\
&=\int_{B}\left(\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_{A }(y+x)dx\right)dy
\\
&=\int_{B}m(A)dy
\\
&=m(A)m(B)
\end{align}